# Syncing data with legacy system

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow, integration

Because of the dreaded SOQL 101 limitation, I have a few flows that run with a delayed path. This is ok, as the processes in the flows do not require to be run instantly. However, in the delayed path I cannot refer to $Record__Prior nor can I set an execution filter based on the IsChanged option.

Now to the synchronisation problem:

When the Salesforce records are created or modified they are synched to the legacy system. The legacy systems API returns a record UNID for each synched Salesforce record. When the record is synched the first time, the Salesforce record is updated with this UNID. With the next synchronisation of changes, this UNID is send to the API so it doesn't create another copy, but updates the existing record with that UNID.

As the Salesforce record is updated it triggers the synchronisation process again. So I need a method not to run into an endless loop (trigger bouncing).

For all instantly running flows for the respective Salesforce records, this is no problem as I can simply skip execution if the UNID field changed (as this field is changed only by the sync process).

However, in the flows running with the delayed path option I cannot tell that this was caused by the synchronisation process and hence if I let the flow run, which in turn updates the record it was triggered for, this will again trigger the synchronisation process...So the system runs into an endless loop causing a CPU time exceeded exception.

Is there any way a flow and an Apex trigger can somewhat communicate with each other to avoid this trigger bouncing? In our legacy system I can create a Code Lock to avoid code being triggered until I remove the Code Lock. Does such thing exist in Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a Code Block in Salesforce. You could create a custom field, and store data there to indicate if it's likely a synchronization.

Comment: This won't work, because you would need to reset the value after the synchronisation is done, triggering again the flow. As the delayed flow cannot check the previous value, I would be back to square one.

Comment: Well, for know I believe to have solved it by having the Apex Trigger ignoring all field changes that are not relevant to the synch process. The calculations the flow does are luckily not required to be send back to the legacy system.

Comment: Having said this, I'm still looking into a generic solution where a Flow can communicate with an Apex Trigger. Not sure if invocable Apex methods will help here. I will post the solution when I find it.

Comment: @user2910531 Any static variables you set in an Apex trigger should be visible to an Apex Action later. That might be a viable solution.